# Hide conversations in Messages

Tags: macos, messages, big-sur

I recently upgraded from High Sierra to Big Sur. Before the upgrade, each conversation in Messages had a little `x` I could click on to hide it.

I can't find that option now, and Message is cluttered with lots of conversations I don't really need to see.

There's a "Delete Conversation" command, but the prompt makes me think that this deletes the conversation permanently. In some cases this is actually what I want (I don't need all my old messages with verification codes), but in other cases I just want to  hide conversations that are inactive, but not lose all the old messages completely.

Did they remove this option completely, or is there a hidden option to restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the "Delete Conversation" command actually does what the old "x" button did. The confirmation dialogue makes it sound like it's going to delete the messages permanently. But I've deleted some conversations since posting this question, and later when I get a message from the same sender, all the old messages are still there.